# Add path parameter in requests

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I would have:
`https://exampleurl/{path}` an URL like this, then what functionality in the `requests` module should I use to fill in the path? I know that I can pass in something like:

`query = {'q0':'path_params','q1':'hello', 'q2':'world'}`

and pass that into `requests.get(url, params=query)`. But that produces something like this:

`https://exampleurl/?q1=hello&q2=world`

instead of `https://exampleurl/path_params?q1=hello&q2=world`

Comment: Literally just add it to the URL string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a string concatenation.

```
url = 'https://exampleurl/'
path = 'home'
url += path
```

```
url = 'https://exampleurl/home'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do string format on the url to fill in the path params.

```
url = 'https://exampleurl/{path_param}'
api_call = url.format(path)
```

Comment: This gives a keyerror. What does work is path='home'; `url.format(path_param=path)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use f-string

```
url = f"https://exampleurl/{path}" 

response = request.get(url, params=query)
```